# Ubuntu: the user has shell, it has no password, but I cannot ssh to it? why?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login

I have a user that has shell:

```
/etc/passwd/ :   /var/lib/myuser:/bin/bash
```

The permit password of /ect/ssh/sshd_config has been set to yes
I can do `sudo su myuser` on the machine and it does not need a password. But when I ssh tot he server using myuser, it asks for password and an empty password does not work?

Can some one please explain, why it cannot ssh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSH daemon by default will not allow connections from users with no passwords.  This is in place for a very good reason, and I highly recommend using SSH keys if you want to connect without typing a password.  If you really want a passwordless connection, you will need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set the following:

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

Once you have updated that flag and restarted the service you should be able to connect without a password.  Again, please do not do this for any machine that has public internet access - your server will be compromised.